# Use the calculate function in a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I can make a macro emulate the calculate manual <kbd>F9</kbd> key, but it only loops once. So I'd like to write a macro that emulates holding down the <kbd>F9</kbd> key to 
calculate the worksheet in a continuous loop.

Comment: Why would someone do that? Excel re-calculates automatically if necessary if calculation is set to automatic.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run calculation with VBA use the [`Application.Calculate` Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195517.aspx).

- All open workbooks `Application.Calculate`
- A specific worksheet `Worksheets("sheetName").Calculate`
- A specified range `Worksheets("sheetName").Range("A1:C3").Calculate`

Comment: Thanks Peh that helps a lot. Ill try and put that in a loop and see what the result is. With the formula i am using i need the calc to loop, for awhile at least then i can continue with the formula.

Comment: @gregg2597 If you think you need to calculate in a loop then you are doing something wrong. If you have a circular reference in your formulas then [see here how to use iterative calculation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123) (bottom). Calculating in a loop is definitely not necessary in Excel. Then there is something wrong in your approach.